# jquery datepicker in jqgrid inline edit select option

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, datepicker

I'm not sure if what i'm asking is possible.

I have a jqgrid with inline edit enable. One of the column has an edit type set to "select".

```
name: 'PayDate',
index: 'PayDate',
align: 'center',
hidden: false,
search: true,
stype: 'select',
searchoptions: { dataUrl: path + '/Helper/FirstPaid?clientId=' + clientId },
editable: true,
edittype: "select",
editoptions: { value: "HIDA:Hiring Date;DATE:Choose a date..." }
```

Here is the result:

[image]

What I would like to do is that when the user click on "Choose a date..." a jquery datepicker appear.

If you have any idea how to achieve it, it will be great.

Thanks in advance